# How to render a table with both column coloring and horizontal lines?

Tags: tables

I am facing a rendering problem when trying to build a table that has both to use custom horizontal lines AND column coloring. In a nutshell, it seems the rendering draws first the lines and then the colored backgrounds of the cells, so that in the final result the horizontal lines get distorted (i.e. wrong visible width) or completely invisible (like the top edge of the cell "This work" in the example below). How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks and regards, Jorge.

P.S. Some notes:

-The final output has to be a .eps that I can send to the journal publisher, I'm currently using dvips for this.

-By no means I'd cling to this code; if there's a better way of achieving the same effect with other package/environments/etc, please let me know!

-The table layout design is beyond my decision scope (yes, I also hate those lines at the top and at the edges, but boss wants it this way!)

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
% Workaround for avoiding vertical lines to be "cut" by horizontal lines
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{array}
% My custom thick vertical line
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
% For thick horizontal lines
\usepackage{boldline}

% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{ColumnHighlightColor}{gray}{0.9}

% My custom colored column
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{ColumnHighlightColor}}c}


\begin{document}

\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}{?l|l?a?c|c|c|c|c?}
\clineB{3-8}{2.0}
\multicolumn{2}{l?}{}& & VLSI'17& ISSCC'17& VLSI'16& ISSCC'15& ISSCC'14\\
\multicolumn{2}{l?}{}& \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{This work}}& [1]& [2]& [3]& [4]& [5]\\ \toprule[1pt]
\multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Input range [V$_{\mathrm{pp}}$]}& 1.6& -& 2.0& -& 2.5& 2.0\\
\multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Sampling rate [Sa/s]}& 600M& 500M& 9G& 2.5G& 500M& 1G\\ \midrule
& LF input& 9.4& 9.1& -& 10.3& 10.5& 11.2\\
\multirow{-2}{*}{ENOB [bit]} & Nyquist& 9.06& 9.1& 10.7& 10& 10.3& 11\\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{SNDR [dB]} & LF input& 58.1& 56.7& -& 64& 64.8& 69\\
& Nyquist& 56.3& 56.6& 66& 61.7& 64& 68\\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{SFDR [dBc]}& LF input& 67.5& 73& 79& 80& 93& 86\\
& Nyquist& 69.2& 69.2& 79& 73& 82& 82\\  \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Power [W]}& 14.2m& 6m& 2330m& 1150m& 550m& 1200m\\
\multicolumn{2}{?l?}{FOMW [J/conv.-step]}& 44f& 22f& 715f& 463f& 849f& 585f\\
\multicolumn{2}{?l?}{FOMS [dB]}& 159.5& 162.8& 152.3& 152.1& 150.6& 154.2\\
\multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Active area [mm$^{2}$]}& 0.621& 0.015& 5.1& -& 2.5& 18\\ \bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{small}


\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `\clineB` with `\cmidrule` and the appropriate parameters:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
% Workaround for avoiding vertical lines to be "cut" by horizontal lines
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{array}
% My custom thick vertical line
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
% For thick horizontal lines
\usepackage{boldline}

% Colors
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ColumnHighlightColor}{gray}{0.9}

% My custom colored column
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{ColumnHighlightColor}}c}


\begin{document}

\begin{small}
  \begin{tabular}{?l|l?a?c|c|c|c|c?}
    %\clineB{3-8}{2.0}
    \cmidrule[0.8pt](l{-1pt}){3-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{l?}{} & & VLSI'17 & ISSCC'17 & VLSI'16 & ISSCC'15 & ISSCC'14 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l?}{} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{This work}} & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] \\ \toprule[1pt]
    \multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Input range [V$_{\mathrm{pp}}$]} & 1.6 & - & 2.0 & - & 2.5 & 2.0 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Sampling rate [Sa/s]} & 600M & 500M & 9G & 2.5G & 500M & 1G \\ \midrule
                                                          & LF input & 9.4 & 9.1 & - & 10.3 & 10.5 & 11.2 \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{ENOB [bit]} & Nyquist & 9.06 & 9.1 & 10.7 & 10 & 10.3 & 11 \\ \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{SNDR [dB]} & LF input & 58.1 & 56.7 & - & 64 & 64.8 & 69 \\
                                                          & Nyquist & 56.3 & 56.6 & 66 & 61.7 & 64 & 68 \\ \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{SFDR [dBc]} & LF input & 67.5 & 73 & 79 & 80 & 93 & 86 \\
                                                          & Nyquist & 69.2 & 69.2 & 79 & 73 & 82 & 82 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Power [W]} & 14.2m & 6m & 2330m & 1150m & 550m & 1200m \\
    \multicolumn{2}{?l?}{FOMW [J/conv.-step]} & 44f & 22f & 715f & 463f & 849f & 585f \\
    \multicolumn{2}{?l?}{FOMS [dB]} & 159.5 & 162.8 & 152.3 & 152.1 & 150.6 & 154.2 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{?l?}{Active area [mm$^{2}$]} & 0.621 & 0.015 & 5.1 & - & 2.5 & 18 \\ \bottomrule[1pt]
  \end{tabular}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image]